# Using for loops in python to print out a calorie burnt table

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

So I have this problem that requires me to print out a table of calories burnt according to body weight for several different times from 15 minutes to 90 minutes growing in the interval of 15 minutes.
I'm having trouble printing out the table with ONLY the use of for loops, since its still early on in the course we're not allowed to use things that haven't been learnt in class yet.
Here is the code i managed to come up with with using arrays:

```
CANOEING=3.5068/60
HIKING=6.0/60
R_BLADING=7.5068/60
T_K_D=10.3014/60
TAICHI=3.0/60
activities=[CANOEING,HIKING,R_BLADING,T_K_D,TAICHI]
activ_name=["Canoeing","Hiking","Rollerblading","Tae Kwon do","Tai chi"]
mass=float(input("Enter your body mass(kg): "))
print("Activity     |Calories in 15m |Calories in 30m |Calories in 45m |Calories in 60m |Calories in 75m |Calories in 90m |")
for j in range(0,5):
    print("{:<13s}|".format(activ_name[j]), end="")
    for i in range(15,91,15):
        c_burnt=i*activities[j]*mass
        print("{:<16.4f}|".format(c_burnt),end="")
    print()
```

the sample output is like this:

```
Enter your body mass(kg): 55
Activity     |Calories in 15m |Calories in 30m |Calories in 45m |Calories in 60m |Calories in 75m |Calories in 90m |
Canoeing     |48.2185         |96.4370         |144.6555        |192.8740        |241.0925        |289.3110        |
Hiking       |82.5000         |165.0000        |247.5000        |330.0000        |412.5000        |495.0000        |
Rollerblading|103.2185        |206.4370        |309.6555        |412.8740        |516.0925        |619.3110        |
Tae Kwon do  |141.6442        |283.2885        |424.9327        |566.5770        |708.2212        |849.8655        |
Tai chi      |41.2500         |82.5000         |123.7500        |165.0000        |206.2500        |247.5000        |
```

how exactly do I get an output like this by only using for loops? I only see a way to approach this by using arrays.
Thanks in advance

EDIT: just for clarification this is supposed to be very basic, all we've learnt so far is data types, print statements and formatting, decision structures, and for loops.

Comment: If you can't use arrays to store the information, is there anything else (like a dictionary?) you can use?  If not, it seems you're left w/ hard coding things, and not even needing loops.

Comment: Your solution looks pretty good to me. If you can't use lists (which are what arrays are called in Python) can you use tuples?

Comment: NB: The Python data type of which you speak is a `list`, not an array. Lists are much more flexible than classic arrays. [Python has an array type](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/array.html) but it's more a speciality type for when space optimization is essential.